# Django HTML button on-click invoke backend function

Tags: html, django, backend, channel

im trying to add to my html a button that appears only on certain events, that works for me but i want to add a onclick script/function that will invoke a backend view.py function that deletes the specific room on click, the **room model is : owner(fk), name, slug.**
and the **user model is : username password1 password2.**

i just need to know how to invoke an onclick event that will call the backend function in my views.

## rooms.html

````
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block title %} Rooms | {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="main">
    <h1>Rooms</h1>
</div>
<div class="rooms-container">
    {% for room in rooms %}
        <div class="room">
            <div class="room-info">
                <h1 class="room-title">{{ room.name }}</h1>
                <a href="{% url 'room' room.slug %}" class="room-join">Join Room</a>
                {% if request.user == room.owner %}
                    <button class="room-delete" id="roomDelete">Delete Room</button>
                {% endif %} 
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
 <!-- todo: add delete room button functionality. -->
{% endblock %} ```
````

## views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages

from .models import Room, Message

@login_required
def rooms(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        room_owner = request.user
        room_name = request.POST['room-name']
        if not Room.objects.filter(slug = room_name).exists():
            if room_name == '' or room_name.isspace() or room_name.startswith(' '):
                messages.info(request, 'Invalid room name, spaces-only or string that starts with spaces is invalid.')
            else:
                new_room = Room(owner = room_owner,name = room_name,slug = room_name)
                new_room.save()
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'That room already exists!, try a different name.')  
    rooms = Room.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'room/rooms.html', {'rooms': rooms})

@login_required
def room(request, slug):
    room = Room.objects.get(slug=slug)
    messages = Message.objects.filter(room=room)[0:25]
    return render(request, 'room/room.html', {'room': room, 'messages': messages})


@csrf_exempt
def delete_room(request): ## <<------ invoke this from html call.
    print("hey")
```

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.rooms, name='rooms'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.room, name='room'),
    path('', views.delete_room, name='delete_room'),
]
```

now i have more 2 urls.py, the project has 3 folders, 1 main (livechatapp) with settings and all, one for core htmls (core) and one for rooms html (room)

## core/urls

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.frontpage, name='frontpage'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='core/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

and finally

## livechatapp/urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('rooms/', include('room.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and this is the projects overview folders and files :
[this is the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcLZ8.png)

Answer (score 0):

IF you want do it in standard html:

````
% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block title %} Rooms | {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="main">
    <h1>Rooms</h1>
</div>
<div class="rooms-container">
    {% for room in rooms %}
        <div class="room">
            <div class="room-info">
                <h1 class="room-title">{{ room.name }}</h1>
                <a href="{% url 'room' room.slug %}" class="room-join">Join Room</a>
                {% if request.user == room.owner %}
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'delete_room' room.slug %}>
                    <button type="submit" class="room-delete">Delete Room</button></form>
                {% endif %} 
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
 <!-- todo: add delete room button functionality. -->
{% endblock %} ```
````

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.rooms, name='rooms'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.room, name='room'),
    path('delete/<slug:slug>/', views.delete_room, name='delete_room'),
]
```

views:

```
@csrf_exempt
def delete_room(request,slug):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        try:
            room = Room.objects.get(slug=slug, owner=request.user)
            room.delete()
            
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            print('there is no room with this slug or you are not owner')

    return redirect('rooms')
```

i advice to use csrf. allways try to use POST when manipulatind data in db.

If you want to work it without redirect you need to think of ajax call or maby htmx

Comment: why do i need the room.slug in the url and the in the path delete/<slug:slug> and is it only possible using forms for the POST ? i wanted a simple button but i understand ur approach i tried it now it doesnt work aswell :<

Comment: somehow you need to tell your backend which room to delete. What does not work?

Comment: it works, my bad, im just trying to understand how all the urls pathing is working i cant get my head around it, when u tell it 'delete/<slug:slug>' and when i tell it 'delete/' or '' in the first path arguement it throws me an error, id love to understand why

Comment: Think of it like that your web browser and Django server is two different applications. When Django response to web browser you see html page. The only way for Django to 'know' what are you trying to do is by URLs. There is no other way. So if you want to delete object you need to tell Django which one to delete. Only way to do it is to pass it's Id in URL or in POST.